# Find a Blackberry in usb in Linux

Tags: linux, blackberry

I just connected my BlackBerry to Linux via USB cable. How do I know which device in /dev it actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `dmesg` after plugging in your Blackberry, you'll get as output something like the following:

```
[33399.504750] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[33399.507712] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

where `sdc` and `sdd` are the device node identifiers.

Or you can execute `hal-device` to list all the devices.

Or even `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*` to list all usb block devices.

Comment: Offtopic: As you are using Linux, I've found this [webpage](http://www.progweb.com/modules/blackberry/index-en.html) which contains valuable information about using your BlackBerry in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The `lsusb` command will help, it will list (`ls`) the USB devices.

You can then compare the device number with the major and minor numbers in your /dev dir.